# Templates base.html no Django

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, django

bom dia!! Estou trabalhando com Templates Django. Acontece que criei um um template base.html que servirá para todos os outros formulários html.Tenho um index.html que extende esse tamplate beleza, mas já tenho outro formLogin.html que também extende o base.html, mas esse (formLogin.html) não está vindo correto, tipo o rodapé não aparece e está sem formatação. O que pode está acontecendo, já que o index.html funciona perfeitamente?:

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" href="/static/img/icone.ico"> <!--Icone da página-->
    <script src="/static/js/angular.min.js"></script>  <!--usando o angular!-->


    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">  <!--usando o bootstrap!-->

    <!-- My styles para esse template -->
    <link href="static/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">  <!--usando o Style CSS!-->



    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <div class="cabeca">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'web.views.login'%}">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

</head>

<body>


{% block content %}


{% endblock content %}


<div id="rodape">

</div>

{% block extra_javascript %}{% endblock extra_javascript %}
</body>
</html>
```

index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block content %}


    <div class="container">

        <div class="starter-template">
            <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
            <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.container -->

{% endblock content %}
{% block extra_javascript %}


{% endblock extra_javascript %}
```

formLogin.html 
(esse que está com problema- não herda tudo que está na base.html)

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block content %}


    <div class="container">


            <h1>TESTE</h1>


    </div><!-- /.container -->


{% endblock content %}

{% block extra_javascript %}

{% endblock extra_javascript %}
```

Comment: Tente ver o código de fonte da página HTML quando renderizar no seu navegador, verifique se a parte do código que você deseja apareceu, veja se o CSS está sendo aplicado, no Chrome, Firefox e Safari você consegue fazer isso. Você diz que o rodapé não aparece, mas o elemento `<div id="rodape"></div>` está vazio.

Comment: O que o `starter-template` do Bootstrap faz? Como apontado por @Orion, seu elemento `#rodape` está vazio, a menos que tenha algum CSS fazendo alguma coisa nele (tipo um `:before` ou `:after`) então ele deveria estar igualmente vazio nos dois casos. Mais provável que seja o Bootstrap que esteja adicionando um *outro* rodapé por conta dele. Sugiro a mesma coisa que o Orion, mas além de olhar o fonte (que talvez não revele nada de anormal) use a opção "inspecionar elemento" para ver o DOM "ao vivo" (i.e. depois do Bootstrap já ter feito a "mágica" dele).

Comment: P.S. Reparei que você tem uma `div` no `head`. Estou assumindo que foi um engano, certo?

Comment: Pois é, esse div está no header. Depois, há os comentários.. evite o comentário <!-- html --> e use {% comment %} {% endcomment %}